# total cost of membership over period at set growth rate per renewal

Tags: calculator

I need to calculate a membership cost.

The first year's membership will be £530, the second year will be £530 + £25, so £555.Every year, the renewal will be an additional £25, so year one = 530, year two = 555, year 3 = 580 and so on.

I need to calculate, based on how long the membership will be, wat the total cot of that membership will be i.e. if it were a 3 year membership it would be 530 + 555 + 580.

Shy of working out each year's cost, then adding them all together, is there a formula I can use to work this out? I'll need to program this into a query, so need the specific equation.

Comment: How are compound interest and interest rate related? Do you need to find the present value?

Comment: I just need to find what the total membership would cost over the lifetime of the mebership

Answer (score 0):

Hint-1: Suppose the first year's membership was $0$ and the membership rose by $1$ each year.  What would the cost be after $n$ years.

Related question: What is the formula for $1 + 2 + \cdots + (n-1)$?

Hint-2: Suppose the first year's membership was $0$ and the membership rose by $k$ each year.  How has that affected the answer given to Hint-1?

Hint-3: Suppose the first year's membership was $n$ and the membership rose by $k$ each year.  How has that affected the answer given to Hint-2?